# Recursive function for the number of recursive calls another function makes (McCarthy 91)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, computer-science

We have the McCarthy 91 function: [image: McCarthy 91 function]
What is a recursion T(n), where T(n) denotes the number of recursive calls made when executing M(n)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to do your homework for you, but try writing a program that rather than just returning M(n), returns both the results of M(n) and the number of recursive calls:

```
def Mx(n):
    """returns M(n) and the number of recursive calls"""
    if n > 100:
        return n - 10, 0
    else:
        a, r0 = Mx(n + 11)
        b, r1 = Mx(a)
        return b, r0 + r1 + 2
```

Run this program on values in the range 0..100.  Do you see a pattern in the value for M(n)?  Do you see a pattern in the number of recursive calls?  Now prove it.

Comment: Theoretical question. No coding is needed for solving it. I’m interested in how to solve this without writing a code for M91 (which I have already done) and trying to work backwards.

Comment: You miss my point. Once you run the code, it'll be clear what the answer is *supposed* to be.  Then your problem becomes to prove the answer that you already know its going to be is correct, rather than guessing what the answer is going to be.  Then prove that using induction.